contourf not showing full color
I was trying to plot the wave1-4 of air temperature from 850hPa with contourf and it worked for wave2-4. But the picture of wave1 just showed the positive part and ignored the negative part. The data of wave1 was not wrong cause the method of fft for all wave number is the same. wave1-4 of t850
That's my code:
t_all = Dataset('t850_all_wave.nc')
t_cli = Dataset('t850_cli_wave.nc')
print(t_all.variables.items())

lat = t_all.variables["latitude"][:]
lon = t_all.variables["longitude"][:]

t_all = t_all.variables["msl"][:]
t_cli = t_cli.variables["msl"][:]

t = np.concatenate((np.array(t_all), np.array(t_cli)))

#%%

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,5))
ax_list = []

#???????????
title = ['(a) t850 - wave1','(b) t850 - wave2','(c) t850 - wave3','(d) t850 - wave4']

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        
        ax = fig.add_axes([0.+0.42*j, 0.+0.6*(1-i), 0.5, 0.5],projection = ccrs.NorthPolarStereo(central_longitude=0))

        ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=False,linewidth=1, color='grey',linestyle='--')

        ax.set_boundary(circle, transform=ax.transAxes)

        ax.set_extent((-180,180,0,90),ccrs.PlateCarree())
        
        cycle_data, cycle_lon = add_cyclic_point(t[2*i+j], coord=lon)
        
        lv = np.arange(-5,5.1,0.5)

        contour1 = ax.contourf(cycle_lon,lat,cycle_data,levels=lv,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),cmap=cmaps.BlueWhiteOrangeRed,extend='both')
        
        contour2 = ax.contour(lon,lat,t[2*i+j+4],levels=[-5,-4.5,-4,-3.5,-3,-2.5,-2,-1.5,-1,-0.5,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5],colors="black",transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),linewidths=1.1)
        
        ax.coastlines(lw = 0.5)
        
        plt.title(title[2*i+j],loc="left")
        
        ax_list.append(ax)

position=fig.add_axes([0.92, 0.05, 0.02, 0.95])
cb = plt.colorbar(contour1,ax=ax_list,cax=position,aspect=30,orientation='vertical',label='Wave 1-4 of t850')

plt.savefig("t850.png", dpi=500, bbox_inches='tight')

Once changing the pace of levels from 0.5 to 0.1, it would work and show all the color.I wonder why the levels of contourf would make the color disappear.

Post a [mre] including sample data.

Possibly an instance of this bug: https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/1076

I think I've found what made the figure so weird...
I thought the data of latitude 90 would be the same 0 at all longitude but it's NOT. For different longitude from -180 to 179, the data of 90N goes like:
masked_array(data=[-1.73169161e-14, -1.83275704e-14, -1.91987421e-14,
               -1.99237989e-14, -2.04972232e-14, -2.09146512e-14,
               ...
               -8.82087152e-15, -1.04742603e-14, -1.20479332e-14,
               -1.35299139e-14, -1.49089251e-14, -1.61744685e-14],
         mask=False,
   fill_value=1e+20,
        dtype=float32)

Since 90N is just a single point, I think those different values at 90N may be the cause of the disappearance of the half color.
